# Does 'barely impossible' mean 'possible'?

Tags: meaning

From [Economic optimisation of European supply chains for CO2 capture, transport and sequestration](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1750583617304139)

> Considering the current state of affairs, it is barely impossible to
> reduce emissions without relying on CO2 capture and sequestration
> technologies.

'barely' is a negative word,and 'impossible' too.So, why do not 'barely impossible' mean 'possible'?

Comment: Why do you think that barely is a negative word?

Comment: @YonKuma [Hardly, scarcely and barely are negative words](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/barely?q=barely)

Comment: What in that dictionary definition makes you think that barely (or either of the other words) are negative?

Comment: @YonKuma Click the Grammar Point in the link above,and you can see that expression.

Comment: Ah, I see. This is a weird case where the grammar of the word (it's treated as negative for the purpose of sentence construction) clashes with the meaning of the word (which is very slightly positive). This may help: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/165532/to-what-extent-is-hardly-a-negative-adverb

Comment: @Michael Harvey How about this sentence 'I had been **barely** an entirely **unprepared** for this line of questioning.' ? Is 'barely' a nagative ?

Comment: @YonKuma Thanks!

Comment: @Mr.Wang Your new sentence is not comprehensible English, for multiple reasons. To answer your core question though, it is unidiomatic to say "barely unprepared" because of the reason given by Michael. I actually adopted an opposite meaning of the original text, understanding it as "may be possible soon with further breakthroughs," but that demonstrates how unidiomatic this usage is.

Comment: @YonKuma I see. Thank you very much!

Comment: Personally, I find [*It is **barely impossible** to...*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22it+is+barely+impossible+to%22) completely unacceptable, so I'm surprised to see how often it has occurred in print. But although that Google Books link shows a *lot* of written instances, it's so *relatively* uncommon compared to [*It is **barely possible** to...*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=It+is+barely+impossible+to%2CIt+is+barely+possible+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) that Google NGrams won't even attempt to show it on the chart. Avoid!

Comment: ...I'm guessing many if not *most* of those written instances are in fact from non-native Anglophones (and nearly all the rest will be typos), so *in principle* this is a valuable question for many learners, even if some natives want to throw their hands up in horror!

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I would be OK with 'nearly impossible' which I would say means very much the same as 'barely possible'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: That's because ***barely*** is a strongly "negative polarity" element, so it doesn't work well with an *already negated* referent. But ***nearly, almost, just,...*** have a sort of "floating polarity", which allows them to be used with negated *and* non-negated referents *(**nearly impossible, almost possible, just impossible,...**)*.

Comment: The example sentence looks like the writer has got confused between "barely possible" and "nearly impossible". It obviously means those things (which mean the same thing), not "only just impossible" or however you would paraphrase "barely impossible".

Comment: No source given for the quote in the question.  vtc as needing more details

Comment: @Michael Harvey I have found it is written by an Italian. I have added the link in the quote.

Comment: Yes, this is an error by a non native speaker.   So there is not much to analyse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first assumption, on seeing that sentence, would be to assume that there was a slip in the editing, and it was meant to be "barely possible."

If it was meant, I would think it meant, "We can come very close to doing it, but not entirely."